# Limit without L'Hopital or infinite series

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have this limit which I had some troubles when trying to solve it 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}
\frac {e^x+e^{-x}-2}{\cos(4x)-\cos(x)}
$$
If someone just gave me a hint.

Comment: Do you know Taylor series then?

Comment: Taylor series expansions of $\cos x$ and $e^x$ as $x \to 0$ give the answer.

Comment: I know them but I can't use them here

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to write that in the question

Comment: Well, thanks for the clarification then.

Comment: What's wrong with l'Hospital ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Sadly, it makes everything too easy.

Comment: I have seen numerous times in this site for exercises without L'Hospital nor Taylor series. I have completely no idea what is the purpose for such exercises. Perhaps one should be referred to *[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+x-%3E0+(e%5Ex%2Be%5E(-x)-2)%2F(cos(4x)-cos(x)))* also?

Comment: Like what @Gribouilis , It makes thins too easy

Comment: @jack ,can u give me those sites plz

Comment: In Olympics they don't let u to use L'Hopitale or series , And I'm just practising that

Comment: You're allowed $\frac{e^x-1}{x} \to 1$ but not l'Hôpital ? It's cheating!

Comment: @user11618: You can check the "Related" question right on this webpage.

Comment: @Gribouillis Well, that's just the derivative of $\exp$ at $0$. One has to be allowed to use *something.*

Comment: Yes, to support @ClementC.'s comment: It is totally abuse of mathematics to use L'Hôpital's rule to do a limit that is in fact the definition of the derivative. This has frustrated me for approximately 40 years of teaching college mathematics.

Answer (score 7):

$$
\begin{align}\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { e^{ x }+e^{ -x }-2 }{ \cos  (4x)-\cos  (x) } &=\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { e^{ 2x }-2{ e }^{ x }+1 }{ \left( { e }^{ x } \right) \left( -2\sin { \frac { 3x }{ 2 }  } \sin { \frac { 5x }{ 2 }  }  \right)  } \\ &=\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { { \left( { e }^{ x }-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ \left( { e }^{ x } \right) \left( -2\sin { \frac { 3x }{ 2 }  } \sin { \frac { 5x }{ 2 }  }  \right)  } \\&=\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { { \left( { e }^{ x }-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { x }^{ 2 } } \cdot \frac { \frac { 3x }{ 2 } \cdot \quad \frac { 5x }{ 2 }  }{ \left( { e }^{ x } \right) \cdot \left( -2\sin { \frac { 3x }{ 2 }  } \sin { \frac { 5x }{ 2 }  }  \right)  } \cdot \frac { 2 }{ 3 } \cdot \frac { 2 }{ 5 } \\ &=-\frac { 2 }{ 15 } \end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh, I like this answer very much.

Comment: Well done!  (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {e^x+e^{-x}-2}{\cos(4x)-\cos(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}
\frac {(e^x-1)+(e^{-x}-1)}{-2\cdot\sin(5x/2)\sin(3x/2)}$$

Use Fundamental Limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\sin x}{x}=1$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {e^x-1}{x}=1$$

Comment: Well, then, this is almost L'Hospital in disguise.

Comment: It depends how that fundamental limits are given in the class.

Comment: @Jack Sh, we prove L'Hospital's in the way that let's us deal with the $\frac\infty\infty$, so there's no L'Hospital's here.

Comment: @Jack Calling $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=f'(x)$ an application of l'Hospital sems a bit of a stretch ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Sure I'm not saying one gets $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$ *by* L'Hospital. The point is that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$ is essentially $(e^x)'\big|_{x=0}=1$. If one is applying this limit (and the other one), then essentially one is applying L'Hopital to the original quotient $\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{\cos(4x)-\cos(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=2t$, so the numerator is
$$
e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2=(e^t-e^{-t})^2
$$
The denominator is
$$
\cos 4x-\cos x=\cos8t-\cos2t=-2\sin5t\sin3t
$$
Thus the limit is
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(e^t-e^{-t})^2}{-2\sin5t\sin3t}=
\lim_{t\to0}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{t}\right)^{\!2}\frac{t}{\sin5t}\frac{t}{\sin3t}
$$
which you can surely compute.

---

With l'Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{\cos 4x-\cos x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{\sin x-4\sin4x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{\cos x-16\cos4x}
$$

With Taylor:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{\cos 4x-\cos x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+1-x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}-2+o(x^2)}
{1-\dfrac{(4x)^2}{2}-1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)}
$$

Comment: Is this appreciably different from the answer posted by @haqnatural ?

Comment: @Dr.MV I was slower in writing it, but at least I didn't finish the exercise for the OP. I decided to keep it because it uses much less symbols.

Comment: That's fair.  So (+1) and Happy Holidays Greg!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{x^{2}}= \lim_{x \to 0} e^{-x}\frac{e^{2x}-2e^x+1}{x^{2}}= \lim_{x \to 0}e^{-x}
\left( \frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)^2= \lim_{x \to 0}e^{-x}
\left( \frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}\right)^2$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}
\frac {\cos(4x)-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}-2
\frac {\sin(\frac{3x}{2})\sin(\frac{5x}{2})}{x^2}=-2\lim_{x \to 0}
\frac {\sin(\frac{3x}{2})}{x}\frac {\sin(\frac{5x}{2})}{x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^x + e^{-x}  - 2 = (e^{\frac {x}{2}} - e^{-\frac {x}{2}})^2 = (2\sinh \frac{x}{2})^2$

What about the denominator.

$\cos a x - \cos bx = \cos (\frac {a+b}{2} + \frac {a-b}{2}) x - \cos (\frac {a+b}{2} - \frac {a-b}{2})x = -2(\sin \frac{a+b}{2} x)(\sin \frac{a-b}{2} x)$

or in this case:

$-2(\sin \frac{5}{2} x)(\sin \frac{3}{2} x)$

$\lim_\limits {x\to 0} = \left(\frac {2 \sinh \frac {x}{2}}{x}\right)^2\left(\frac {x}{-2\sin \frac 52 x}\right)\left(\frac {x}{\sin \frac 32 x}\right) = \frac {1}{-2\cdot\frac {5}{2}\cdot\frac {3}{2}} = -\frac {2}{15}$

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different approach for dealing with the denominator, note that

$$(\cos4x-\cos x)(\cos4x+\cos x)=\cos^24x-\cos^2x=\sin^2x-\sin^24x=(\sin x-\sin4x)(\sin x+\sin4x)$$

and $\cos4x+\cos x\to2$ as $x\to0$, so that

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\cos4x-\cos x\over x^2}={1\over2}\left(\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x\over x}-\lim_{x\to0}{\sin4x\over x} \right)\left(\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x\over x}+\lim_{x\to0}{\sin4x\over x} \right)={1\over2}(1-4)(1+4)=-{15\over2}$$

Putting this together with

$${e^x-2+e^{-x}\over x^2}=\left(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}\over x\right)^2$$

and

$${e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}\over x}={e^{x/2}-1\over x}-{e^{-x/2}-1\over x}\to{1\over2}-{-1\over2}={1\over2}+{1\over2}=1$$

gives the answer ${1^2\over-15/2}=-{2\over15}$.